# Prevent the XHR response from being stolen

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, security

If I have a client side app, for example, jquery mobile or something similar running in a mobile device, that needs to communicate to remove servers.

How can i prevent a XHR response from being stolen? A json response from the remote server.

I found an [article](https://www.golemtechnologies.com/articles/data-security-and-json) about that, but the solution is server side code, and I am not able to use any server language.

Basically the app sends `user_id 1` and the remote server returns the client data.

HTTPS will not work, because the mobile app is outside of the server. So what is the correct way to handle this situation?

Comment: Encrypt the data with a public/private key-principle.

Comment: How about a JSONP and HTTPS?

Comment: What does "stolen" mean? It sounds like you need authentication.

Comment: @SLaks Authentication means sessions or cookies. i don't have any way to avoid cookie manipulation since i can't store a secret key in the app.

Comment: @anvd: If you can't authenticate, you don't have any security in the first place.  How do you tell who is allowed to see data?

Comment: Without authentication there's nothing stopping some random Joe from using your api if they somehow find the endpoint. Since the random joe wouldn't need to use your app to make the request, there's nothing you can do with the app to stop them from making the request from a desktop browser, or a local server.

Comment: @SLaks true. But the problem is basically the same. I don't have any idea how can i add security to logins, XHR or cookies in a pure client side app, since everything can be manipulated.

Comment: @KevinB please see the comment to Slaks. thanks

Comment: @anvd **you can't**. that's the point we are making. This has to be done at the remote server first.

Comment: @KevinB ok, I understand. So basically the option is a web based app with client and server code or native. Phonegap, for example, is useless if the app needs a login or remote requests with sensitive data.

Comment: correct. If the authentication isn't handled by the remote API, nothing you can do client-side will prevent someone from interacting with the api. Abstracting the path to the api is pointless as that can be retrieved using request sniffing to find the requests being made by the application. At that point you would be able to make the requests manually, bypassing any protections you included in the client app.

Comment: You can make it hard for users who aren't looking for the information to find it, but for someone looking for it, it would be easy.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the client is written in.  You need some server-side way to determine who can read what.

Comment: @SLaks so, the only option to have a pure client side app is to make a login check to a remote server before each request, since the app can't store anything persistently in a secure way? the question is about this. The possible ways.

Comment: @anvd: If you already have the data, there is nothing wrong with persisting it.  You need to stop attackers from getting it in the first place.